# Using packages adjustbox and ltablex together

Tags: tabularx, adjustbox, ltablex, scalebox

I am creating a long table spanning multiple pages using the `ltablex` package. I would like to accommodate more content in the same page using the `adjustbox` package to shrink it a bit and increasing table size by manipulating `\textwidth`. But it seems that `ltablex` and `adjustbox` packages are incompatible with each other. I also tried `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package which also throws similar errors. Any suggestions or workarounds? I have included my code just in case.

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[10,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.2\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{X X X X X X X}

\textbf{Tumors}
    & \textbf{Epidemiology}
    & \textbf{Etiology}
    & \textbf{Pathogenesis} 
    & \textbf{Clinical manifestation} 
    & \textbf{Diagnostic workup} 
    & \textbf{Morphology} 
    \\
    
\toprule

Hepatocellular adenomas
    & Women taking estrogen rich oral contraceptives and body builders taking anabolic steroids
    & 30 to 40 fold higher in oral contraceptive users compared to nonusers 
    & Inactivation of HNF1-$\alpha$, activation of $\beta$-Catenin, and chronic irritation of inflammatory processes
    & 50\% are asymptomatic, mild ill-defined abdominal pain in right hypochondrium or epigastrium, bloating, hepatomegaly with mild tenderness
    & Elevated ALP, GGT, and within range $\alpha$-FP as long as the lesion doesn't become malignant. WBC, fibrinogen, CRP maybe elevated. Core needle biopsy is useless unless stained with immuno-histochemical stains. US fails to dx. Dynamic MRI with hepatocyte specific contrast agent is the best modality. Dynamic CT can also be useful at times. 
    & HNF1-$\alpha$ mutated are fatty and devoid of cellular or architectural atypia. $\beta$-Catenin mutated have a high degree of cytologic or architectural dysplasia. Adenomas due to inflammatory processes are comprised only of hepatocytes and vessels with minor amounts of stroma. 
    \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: never scale tables! even when it desn't give an error it produces horrible output, and can not work for multi-page tables at all, simply use `\small` or `\footnotesize` to select a smaller font before the table

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. It worked like a charm. I'll make sure not to scale tables again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could make your table fit onto a page, while reducing the amount of white space in it. I have added the `geometry` package in order to allow for smaller margins, used a `\small` font size in combination with a smaller horizontal separation between adjacent columns (reduced value of `tabcolsep`), `xltabular` instead of `ltablex`/`tabularx` ssuming that your actual table spans more than one page and left aligned `X` type columns with slightly different widths depending on the length of the text in each column. Since tables can only be broken across pages between table rows as oposed to within table rows, you might get an undesired output if you add more rows with comarably long texts. I therefore included an entirely different approach of presenting the information: nested `description` lists:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
{\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}*{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.85\hsize}X} *{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=1.375\hsize}X}@{}}

\textbf{Tumors}
    & \textbf{Epidemiology}
    & \textbf{Etiology}
    & \textbf{Pathogenesis} 
    & \textbf{Clinical manifestation} 
    & \textbf{Diagnostic workup} 
    & \textbf{Morphology} 
    \\
    
\toprule
\endhead

Hepatocellular adenomas
    & Women taking estrogen rich oral contraceptives and body builders taking anabolic steroids
    & 30 to 40 fold higher in oral contraceptive users compared to nonusers 
    & Inactivation of HNF1-$\alpha$, activation of $\beta$-Catenin, and chronic irritation of inflammatory processes
    & 50\% are asymptomatic, mild ill-defined abdominal pain in right hypochondrium or epigastrium, bloating, hepatomegaly with mild tenderness
    & Elevated ALP, GGT, and within range $\alpha$-FP as long as the lesion doesn't become malignant. WBC, fibrinogen, CRP maybe elevated. Core needle biopsy is useless unless stained with immuno-histochemical stains. US fails to dx. Dynamic MRI with hepatocyte specific contrast agent is the best modality. Dynamic CT can also be useful at times. 
    & HNF1-$\alpha$ mutated are fatty and devoid of cellular or architectural atypia. $\beta$-Catenin mutated have a high degree of cytologic or architectural dysplasia. Adenomas due to inflammatory processes are comprised only of hepatocytes and vessels with minor amounts of stroma. 
    \\
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}}

\newpage

\begin{description}
\item[Hepatocellular adenomas]\hfill
  \begin{description}
  \item[Epidemiology] Women taking estrogen rich oral contraceptives and body builders taking anabolic steroids
  \item[Etiology] 30 to 40 fold higher in oral contraceptive users compared to nonusers 
  \item[Pathogenesis] Inactivation of HNF1-$\alpha$, activation of $\beta$-Catenin, and chronic irritation of inflammatory processes
  \item[Clinical manifestation] 50\% are asymptomatic, mild ill-defined abdominal pain in right hypochondrium or epigastrium, bloating, hepatomegaly with mild tenderness
  \item[Diagnostic workup] Elevated ALP, GGT, and within range $\alpha$-FP as long as the lesion doesn't become malignant. WBC, fibrinogen, CRP maybe elevated. Core needle biopsy is useless unless stained with immuno-histochemical stains. US fails to dx. Dynamic MRI with hepatocyte specific contrast agent is the best modality. Dynamic CT can also be useful at times.
  \item[Morphology] HNF1-$\alpha$ mutated are fatty and devoid of cellular or architectural atypia. $\beta$-Catenin mutated have a high degree of cytologic or architectural dysplasia. Adenomas due to inflammatory processes are comprised only of hepatocytes and vessels with minor amounts of stroma. 
  \end{description}
\end{description}



\end{document}
```